# How To Detect Two Characters (Keys) Pressed At The Same TIme

Tags: javascript, keypress

An important distinction is that it is easier to know if `cntrl` and `z` are pressed at the same time, but not as straight forward to detect if `z` and `x` are pressed at the same time. What is the best way to go about detecting when multiple characters are pressed at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example uses event listeners to keep track of an object which contains all keys currently being pressed.

We can use this object to check if certain keys are pressed. This means that we can detect as many simultaneous key presses as a user's keyboard will allow.

Importantly it will let you detect when multiple characters are pressed at the same time.

```js
const keysPressed = {};

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (!event.repeat)
    keysPressed[event.key] = true;
  
  //You can also include event.repeat as a condition in your cases if you wish an event to only occur once each trigger.
  //You can also include Object.keys(keysPressed).length === 2 (for example) if you only wish the case to be valid if just two keys are pressed.
  //Finally, instead of event.key === 'x' you can write keysPressed['x']. This would replace both non-default cases in the example. The result is that the event will continue firing if another key is pressed.
  switch (true) { //You use true here because we are using logic to determine each case
    case event.key === 'x' && keysPressed['z']:
    case event.key === 'z' && keysPressed['x']:
      console.log('Z and X pressed!');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  if (!event.repeat)
    delete keysPressed[event.key];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm simply using an array as storage for all keys that are pressed. This array is cleaned to an empty state when keys are released.

In keydown event listener, you can hook the function with logic that you will want to implement. Read `keys` array to check all currently pressed keys.

```js
const keys = []
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  !event.repeat && keys.push(e.key)
  doSomethingWithKeys(keys)
})
document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  keys.splice(0, keys.length)
})

function doSomethingWithKeys(keys) {
  console.log('keys pressed:', keys.join('+'))
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would recommend sticking to objects as they are more optimized than arrays. This is more because most/all browsers always have objects highly optimized. Speed of `.splice` varies.

Comment: It's just another option with a more bare bone approach. I like your variant though.